# why is the second open sell order didn't execute?

Tags: mql4

```
if(Sell==true && Count.Buy()==0){
        int ticket = Trade.OpenBuyOrder(_Symbol,lotSize);
        int gSellTicket = OrderSend(_Symbol,OP_SELL,0.1,Bid,Slippage,(Bid+(900*Point)),0,"Sell order",NewMagicNumber,0,clrRed);
        lastBuy=NormalizeDouble(FindLastBuyPrice(),Digits);
   }
```

Above code is copied from an EA, i attach it to chart, it execute the first buy order but it did not execute the second sell order. i want to know how to solve this problem. Note: The problem is not hedge is disallowed in the account (Demo or Real) or platform (FXTM) type, i already found out. Thank you in advance for anybody's answer.

Comment: most likely `Bid` is outdated and need to call `RefreshRates()` after buy is sent in order to refresh Bid price. Anyway, it is possible that you will write 100,000 lines of codes some day... Are you going to ask every problem here (and wait for reply) instead of using the logging and debugger?

Comment: Thank you Daniel for the answer and also for he suggestion to use logging and debugger.